# How do I unescape Cyrillic codes received and escaped over serial term

Tags: python, character-encoding, escaping, utf, cyrillic

I am using miniterm.py to receive some data over a serial port. Since I was getting unprintable characters, I added -D (escape unprintable characters) argument to miniterm.py with the hope that I might to un-escape received characters at a later instant. What I know is that there are some Cyrillic characters interspersed with english characters but, I am not able to correlate escaped characters to their Cyrillic equivalents.
following is a sample output

```
\x8c\x84  Pump being primed
\x8c\x90  Discharge valve opened
```

I have had a glance at the miniterm.py script and it seems that it uses repr function to escape characters. I would be grateful if somone could shed some light on the way to decode the characters.

Answer (score 1):

Got my answer a few minutes after asking the question 
Answer is as follows.

Characters are encoded in Code page 866 (Code page 866 (CP 866) is a code page used under MS-DOS to write Cyrillic script). 
Convert the escaped hex sequence to its equivalent decimal value and look-up the value in the [code table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_866)

```
\x8c\x84  is МД
\x8c\x90  is МР
```

Simple t'was

Answer (score 0):

In my case I've end up with the following:

```
In [1]: s = '\xd0\xb0'
In [2]: print(s.decode('utf-8'))
а
```

Probably that's because I'm on Linux where utf is default